# How to redirect mydomain.io to mydomain.com

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, redirect

I have a site mydomain.io, and I want to setup an HTACCESS file to redirect all of mydomain.io/* (including www.mydomain.io/*) to mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com

Could you please advise how to achieve this with htaccess?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess of `domain.io`:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.io$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```